# How to SymLink multiple Folders together

Tags: permissions, nfs, symbolic-link

First off, I'm not a huge Linux person. I can get around, I'm familiar with some Linux structuring, and barely anything with the CLI. So please bear with me while I stumble around like a drunk fool at Mardi Gras.

I have 3 folders in 4 different user accounts.

- User1 has Archives, Documentation, Sources
- User2 has Archives, Documentation, Sources
- User3 has Archives, Documentation, Sources
- User4 has Archives, Documentation, Sources

I need to link these 3 directories to NFS Mounts under /mnt/storage01, /mnt/storage01a, and /mnt/storage02/

I haven't tested it yet, but I haven't heard any complaints from them yet. When I went to do the second account, I got this error;

```
jumpbox@us01-jumpbox:/home/User1$ sudo mkdir Archives
jumpbox@us01-jumpbox:/home/User1$ sudo mkdir Documentation
jumpbox@us01-jumpbox:/home/User1$ sudo mkdir Sources
jumpbox@us01-jumpbox:/home/User1$ ln -s /home/User2/Archives /mnt/storage01
jumpbox@us01-jumpbox:/home/User1$ ln -s /home/User2/Documentation /mnt/storage01a
jumpbox@us01-jumpbox:/home/User1$ ln -s /home/User2/Sources /mnt/storage02
jumpbox@us01-jumpbox:/home/User1$ ln -s /home/User1/Archives /mnt/storage01    
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/mnt/storage01/Archives': File exists
jumpbox@us01-jumpbox:/home/User1$
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Any solid suggestions on how I can get this done?

Comment: You probably want mount --bind .

Comment: Are you trying to link user folders to the storage? or vise versa  `ln -s /full/path/of/original/folder /full/path/of/soft/link/file`

Comment: I want to link the folder in /home/user1/Archives to /mnt/storage01, and so on, however I want to do it for any number of users I have, without changing the folders in the User Directory.

Comment: yes but which direction? if you want to give all users access to storage, then John Oriion's answer is correct. you have your link syntax backwards.

Comment: What do you expect when you do `cd /mnt/storage01; ls -l`? All files from `/home/User1/Archives`? Or all files from `/home/User1/Archives` ***plus*** all files from `/home/User2/Archives` ***plus*** all files from `/home/User3/Archives`?

Comment: I'm trying to keep the users from having direct access to the storage arrays. So, I created NFS mounts to /mnt/Storage01, storage01a, and storage02. I was creating symlinks between the user accounts to these folders. A lot of the people accessing this information aren't computer savvy and would struggle with anything command related. 3 of the 4 users will be using straight sftp to access all of the information.

Comment: Ah, so it's just the other way round. I misunderstood that. You want your User1 to do a `cd /home/User1/Archives; ls -l` and then see the contents of `/mnt/storage01`, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, @PerlDuck. I have a stupidly complex setup for something that shouldn't be so complex. When I get my other servers and storage arrays online, I'll re-do everything but for now, this is how it has to be.

Comment: OK. Then I can now upvote John's answer with a clear conscience. ;-)

Comment: Alright. Thanks guys! I was racking my brains for hours last night trying to figure out what I did wrong. This helped me out massively. I'll be book marking this, and upvoting if i can!

Answer (score 4):

dont make the directories in the users folder .. if the folders already exist it wont be able to create the link ... also you probably need to use the sudo

so delete the folders you made in User1 and User2

and create the following links

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/storage01 /home/User2/Archives
sudo ln -s /mnt/storage01a /home/User2/Documentation
sudo ln -s /mnt/storage02 /home/User2/Sources
```

and so on

link works as ln (link) -s (softlink/symbolic link) (this folder or file) to (this area/ folder) or

```
ln -s /FolderYouWantToHaveLinkedTo /FolderWhereYouWantTheLinkToGo
```

Comment: sudo isn't necessary if he is the owner of the folder the link is placed in.

Comment: yeah but he is in user 1 and trying to make links to User 2 so that is why i suggest sudo .. also I tried without sudo to make a folder link to the /tmp directory from my home directory .. without sudo it made the link but not a folder and not accessible .. I had to use sudo to have it show up as a clickable folder link.

Comment: yes and he is trying to link a root owned folder to user folders ... he is using NTFS so its root with all read/write access since NTFS doesnt deal with linux permissions. I think he will still be needing sudo but .. maybe not maybe he can sign in as each user and not use sudo

Comment: which would be preferable, if  he uses sudo then the link will be owned by root .... a possible source of some issues.

Comment: @JohnOrion He uses NFS, not NTFS.

Comment: @ravery You do _not_ need root permissions to create something in `/tmp`. That's the nature of `/tmp`: everybody can do there what he wants _with his own files_.

Comment: Yes, correct. I'm using NFS.

Comment: @PerlDuck ahh my eyes are seeing things lol .. i saw ntfs :D lol... I still feel my solution would work for him ... but he may have to play with permissions

Comment: Well.. Permissions are going to be fun to begin with. I use NFS because of ACLs, and because Windows doesn't deal with NFS very well, at least that I've been able to figure out. I use Samba for Linux. I run ZFS RAIDz2, so permissions will be fun.

Comment: @ravery also the link may be created in root .. you may need root to delete it but .. when it links it .. it links it as the original folders user:group so .. even though the link is made in root .. my example of the user/bin folder being linked to the /tmp/bin folder .. the link still had the permissions and owner:group of the user/bin folder

Comment: From `man chmod`: _"chmod  never  changes  the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system call cannot change their permissions.  This is
       not a problem since the **permissions of symbolic links are never used.**  However, for each symbolic link listed on the com‐
       mand  line,  chmod changes the permissions of the pointed-to file."_ Links always have 777 so the owner of the link doesn't matter.

Comment: This is useful information to those who dont understand .. I did a chmod and chown  command on my www folder that has some links in it .. you do have to be aware that the chmod / chown commands dont change the linked folders .. if you want to change ownership or permissions you have to change them in the original folder that the link points too.